# Spark SQL: Empty table join with large table slow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have 2 table

1. Transaction table (partition by year)
2. metadata table (All key is unique no partition, 30M records)
   My Spark SQL is

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE PARTITION_YEAR = 2022; (result: 0 record)
> ```

Very fast to get result

> SELECT * FROM Metadata WHERE KEY = "A" (result: 1 record)

2-3 seconds to get result

and finally

> SELECT * FROM Transaction t LEFT JOIN Metadata m ON t.key = m.key WHERE t.PARTITION_YEAR = 2022;

Pretty slow (3 mins.)

Although

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE PARTITION_YEAR = 2022) t LEFT JOIN Metadata m ON t.key = m.key;

Still have to wait (3 mins)

Comment: seems spark is scanning through all the files, what is the file format of the table ? I will suggest to chnage to parquet if not which gives better in scanning optimization

Comment: parquet format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Query behaviour , I am guessing your file format is **parquet**.

```
SELECT * FROM Metadata WHERE KEY = "A"
```

This is like a filter operation which supports PUSHDOWN filter and it won't scan the whole table , rather quickly look at the parquet metadata (RANGE) of your interested column (KEY) and figure out .

But when you join in Spark :
It has to bring in the **Whole table of METADATA into memory**, and it has to scan and shuffle the data based on your join condition. i.e. PUSHDOWN filter is not supported for joins.

---

Your last 2 queries are essentially same. Spark will only bring 2022 data into memory. Even though your partition might be empty, 30M records of METADATA will be loaded.

---

Incase you want to avoid this situation for empty partitions, you should check if the partition is empty then only fire the

The cheapest/efficient way to check :

```
val dfPartition = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE PARTITION_YEAR = 2022;")

if(!dfPartition.isEmpty()) // fastest. 
{
  //Fire your join query
}
```

Comment: Can I hint it to check transaction table before load metadata ? or do something to optimise it.

Comment: better to safe by explicitly having a check. Added in answer.

Comment: Can I do somethings like "SELECT * FROM Transaction t LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Metadata WHERE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Transaction WHERE t.PARTITION_YEAR = 2022 )) m ON t.key = m.key WHERE t.PARTITION_YEAR = 2022;"

Comment: Run it once. I am not sure how spark's logical plan would look like for this SQL. Ideally it should not take more than 5 seconds.